# Sketch, how to cut shapes?

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

I am using Sketch to create a logo. I have 3 shapes (circle and square combined for the fist 2 shapes) that i want to lined up next each other (see image below). 
How would i go about cutting the covering shape so that the one below does not show the extra "bits"?

[concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnrPG.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the circles as B (at the back), M (middle) and F (front)...

1. Duplicate M, creating duplicate D in exactly the same place.
2. Select D and F.
3. Use the 'Intersect' function to create a shape which is the overlap of D and F, with no remaining "bits", leaving you with B > M > D+F